# How to control data transmission from one object to another

Tags: java

I have a two objects one is data giving object another one is data reviving that is jfreechart XYSeries object, the data giving object can pass five data at each millisecond but the XYSeries can handle only one data at each second

My question is how to handle the data without any wait or any disturbance of sender object in java

My code like

```
Public void inputAPI(int x,int y){
    XYSeries.add(x,y);
}
```

Comment: So, either you have a produce/consumer pattern or an observe pattern

Comment: How is this different from all other similar producer-consumer type questions?

Comment: If you need to see more possible duplicates, please have a look at [this search of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+producer+consumer).